# Client side validation is not working in syncfusion controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, syncfusion

I have created one simple project which has one syncfusion grid page and one Registration form. But I am facing a problem with the client side validation on both grid and registration form as well.

I have prepared a sample, which can be downloaded from the below link:-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/68m7syiai5ngu12/SyncfusionApplication.7z?dl=0

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the sample shared by you Jquery files were referred twice in your application which is the root cause of the issue. Try to refer the required Jquery files in the Head section  in the order given in the below code example.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>@ViewBag.Title - Amit</title>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

@Styles.Render("~/Content/ej/web/bootstrap-theme/ej.web.all.min.css")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jsrender.min.js")

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ej/web/ej.web.all.min.js")

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ej/common/ej.unobtrusive.min.js")


@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

I have modified the sample that is provided by you which can be downloaded from the below location.

Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/208562/7z/SyncfusionApplication-2017714476.7z